# MS SQL Server not coming out of Emergency Mode

Tags: sql-server

I have a database which started showing restoring message and i googled and found following steps.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET EMERGENCY;
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyDB set single_user
GO
DBCC CHECKDB (MyDB, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS;
GO
```

and these commands are successfully executed.

But the help told me to run the following 2 commands to make things normal again. But when i try to execute them, it continues executing for over 24 hours. MyDB is a small size DB less of than 50MB.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB set multi_user
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyDBset online
GO
```

So now MyDB is showing emergency in front of the DB name. So is there any solution?

Just to add that i can access DB in emergency mode and i have run few queries and everything seems to be okay.
I have MS SQL 2012.

Comment: Dont know the exact situation here but for >>But when i try to execute them, it continues executing for over 24 hours. Can you check if the the alter statement is blocked ?

Comment: @Shanky It worked fine the first time when i ran
ALTER DATABASE MyDB set single_user
GO

Comment: What do you mean by first time ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the database is experiencing some sort of corruption or other issue that is preventing the commands from completing successfully. In this case, you may need to try some additional steps to troubleshoot the issue.

Check the SQL Server error log for any messages related to the database or the ALTER DATABASE commands. This may give you some insight into what is causing the commands to take so long.

Check the Windows event log for any system or hardware errors that may be affecting the database.

Try restarting the SQL Server instance or the entire server to see if that helps.

Try restoring a backup of the database from before the issue occurred. This is generally the safest and most reliable way to recover from a database corruption or other issue.

In any case, it's important to make sure you have a reliable backup of the database before attempting any repairs or recovery steps. This will ensure that you can restore the database to a known good state if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please be mindful when you run the below command. As per the MS [DBCC checkdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#repair_allow_data_loss--repair_fast--repair_rebuild) running CHECKDB WITH repair allow data loss should be the last option.

Since you already ran it, I would suggest trying to run the below command again. In another session, open the activity monitor and see where the session is waiting and for what in the wait type.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB set multi_user
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyDBset set online
GO
```

If the issue persists please share the error logs so that we can further understand.